# tokenize long list using DCG

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

if I want to tokenize a long list using DCG, what is the preferable methode between the two predicate below ;

**1- using ['terminal']**

```
some_terminals(T) -->
     ['this('],end(T),[')END'].
```

**2-using "terminal"**

```
some_terminals(T) -->
     "this(",end(T),")END".
end(T)-->[T].
```

**Other question**

what is the difference between `;` and `|`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what method will be available to read raw input.
The second one it's what is immediately useful after a read_line, while the first requires a tokenizer.

But a tokenizer, at least a reusable one, should return instead these tokens.

```
some_terminals(T) -->
     [this,'('],end(T),[')','END'].
```

Also, it should handle whitespace, comments, and the like. Whitespaces usually carries semantic, and in some languages like Python are also structurally fundamental.

About the difference between ; & |, there is none. Both are syntax sugar for Prolog disjunction (i.e. multiple clauses with same functor/arity)

Comment: @CappeliC  in my opinion I prefer the first because it clarify the trace of execution if I use trace / 0 (Instead of ambiguous codes),
but logically, I think  that the second is faster because eventually,the inputs will be transformed into codes

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you can use atom type and second case better for string type.If you do more functions then the first is the best.If there are handing with string type second is good.methods are depend on the specification.

Then `;` and `|` are functionally same both are used for `or` operation. but `list-->[a;b;c]` gives some results `|` give error to write like that.
`?- list(S,[]).`
`S = [ (a;b;c)].`

**Edit**
string type

```
det --> "a".
noun --> "cat".
det_noun-->det,noun.

?- det_noun("acat",[]).
true.
```

Atom Type

```
det --> [a].
noun --> [cat].
det_noun-->det,noun.

?- det_noun([a,cat],[]).
true.
```

Comment: thnks,I think that string is subtype of atom can you explain the difference between both types

Comment: See the Edit.more reference about [dcg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar)

Comment: `[a;b;c]` is invalid syntax. Only SWI accepts this.